# VSTS Process Customization Questions (Inheritance process model)

Tags: azure-devops

I have two questions about the customization of a process in VSTS

1. Is there a simple way to make the fields conditionally read-only, visible as simple as we make it required? (simpler than creating a new component)
2. Is there a way to control the workflow of the new states, to forbid removed items to turn into done without going back to new
3. Is there an example of gridcontrol, like the test case steps, to download and make a new control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your questions:

> 1. Is there a simple way to make the fields conditionally read-only,
>      visible as simple as we make it required? (simpler than creating a new
>      component)

No, read only ([Assign value rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/apply-rule-work-item-field#assign-value-rules)) is not available for VSTS (Inheritance process model). You can only (de)select it as **Required** or use custom rules to conditionally change the field as read only.

[image]
[image]

> 2. Is there a way to control the workflow of the new states, to forbid
>      removed items to turn into done without going back to new

There are no such settings/configurations for that. But you can develop an extension for a new Save button to check the work item revisions.

> 3. Is there an example of gridcontrol, like the test case steps, to
>      download and make a new control.

For VSTS work item custom control, you can refer [Add a custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/custom-controls-process). And it also shows related extension [Multivalue control](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.vsts-extensions-multivalue-control).

Comment: Thanks. I created one uservoice item with this questions.https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32001382-create-custom-rules-in-inherited-processes-to-make